# MongoDB Aggregation: Add each array value to each object inside array from another field. Merge/Combine two arrays from different fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am in the middle of complex aggregation query (with lookup and many group/unwind stages) and encounter problem with combining two different arrays from different fields.

As for now, after one of the stages (in the middle or after lookup of my big query) I have the following output:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  quantity: [2, 1, 3]
  reagents: [ 
     {name: "FirstItem", other_field: ... },
     {name: "SecondItem", other_field: ... },
     {name: "ThirdItem", other_field: ... }
  ]
}
```

And I want:

```
  _id: 1,
  reagents: [ 
     {name: "FirstItem", quantity: 2 },
     {name: "SecondItem", quantity: 1 },
     {name: "ThirdItem", quantity: 3 }
  ]
```

So each `[quantity]` value I want to add to every object inside `[reagents]` as field according to it's index, like first `{object}` inside `reagents` should have first `element` from `[quantity]`

Schema with array indexes):

```
quantity: [2, 1, 3, ... n]
           ↓  ↓  ↓      ↓
reagents: [1, 2, 3, ... n]
```

> THE PROBLEM:

I cannot do it after or before aggregation because:

- I don't have a necessary data, cause it's result of lookup from different collections.
- I cannot do it after because right after this, I should `$group` data by another field, so `[reagents]` sorting order have been lost and cannot be restored.

**UPD**: *I understand that I could (and probably should use `$unwind` stage for `[reagents]` but I haven't found [any relevant Aggregation Stage Operators in Mongo Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/). So if you know a necessary one, please point me in.*

Comment: Do you need to keep other fields in reagents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add below stage

```
 { "$addFields": {
   "reagents": {
     "$map": {
       "input": { "$range": [0, { "$size": "$reagents" }] },
       "in": {
         "name": {
           "$arrayElemAt": ["$reagents.name", "$$this"]
         },
         "quantity": {
           "$arrayElemAt": ["$quantity", "$$this"]
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }}
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a_8lmu5sz5M)

Comment: Just "wow". I have heard something about `MapReduce`, but I have never would thought that `$addFields` with `map` could be my solution. I'll dig to the botton of it.

Answer (score 3):

@Ashh's answer will work perfectly (and afaik is the best solution) if you don't need to keep other fields than name and quantity in your results.
But if you have to keep them, you'll have to add each field manually, what can be sometimes tedious.
There's another 'general' solution to resolve this case, with [$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) operator which is designed to merge arrays by index.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      reagents: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              inputs: [
                "$quantity",
                "$reagents"
              ]
            }
          },
          as: "reagent",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$$reagent",
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                quantity: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$$reagent",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GuTPb1d6yag)

Comment: Yea, thank you so much. You answer is also relevant, because in my case `[reagents]` also have other fields too.